# appregnew.aspx for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, app

When I try to access `https:// -site- /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx`, I get an error telling me that I don't have access to this site.

I work on Sharepoint 2013 and I found that this method works only for Sharepoint Online.

Do you know what can I use to replace it? I need to register an app for an external application

**Note:** I don't have Azure, and I can't have it.

Comment: What permissions do you have on your SharePoint 2013 site?

Comment: I have admin permission on my Sharepoint, full control I guess

Comment: Please check and confirm...Are you site collection administrator? Check permissions from Site settings-->Site permissions-->Check Permissions.

Comment: I checked and I have full control

Comment: Please check this URL, it may help: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220974/cannot-access-appregnew-aspx-for-registering-oauth-for-rest-access

Comment: you need site collection administrator permissions for this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for both SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013/2016 on-premises:

```
https:// -site- /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx
```

In order to access this page you must be **Site Collection Administrator**. Only Full Control access will not work for this.

Check if you are Site Collection Administrator or not from Site settings--> Site permissions--> Site Collection Administrators.

**Reference**:

[Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, is it possible to do it on Sharepoint Foundation or is it only for Sharepoint Server/Online ?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your post, it saved my life. I wasn't aware that we had to be Site Collection Administrators to access this page, even if the site owner granted us full control...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using wrong path. Below will take you to root site collection.

```
https:// -site- /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx
```

Can you try to access(if not already doing)

```
https://yourdomain.com/sites/yoursitecollection/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx
```

If you are site collection administrator of site collection you should be able to access.